# Why it should be 'estimated', instead of 'is estimated'?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, adjectives, sentence-choice, past-participles

The hurricane caused damage ......... at $300 million.

What I have chosen: is estimated

The answer should have been: **estimated**

Is *estimated* adjective, what type of adjective, or what parts of speech would be the case?

Comment: You would need 'damage **which** is (or has been) estimated...' to make sense. This meaning is implied by using **estimated** alone.

Comment: It may be grammatical to say "The hurricane-caused damage is estimated at $300 million", but this would be far more clunky and less natural than the presented alternative.

Comment: "You would need 'damage which is (or has been) estimated..." I am enlightened -Keep forgetting this...Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"is estimated" would form a passive voice sentence, but what then would be the subject.  The parts before "The hurricane caused damage" already has a finite verb.

If you use "is estimated" you get an expression with two main verbs.

Instead the (past/passive) *participle* "estimated" does fit in the gap.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence fragment you give: *The hurricane caused damage...* has a subject (*The hurricane*) and a verb (*caused*) and an object (*damage*).

If you add a single hyphen: *The hurricane-caused damage...* changes the phrasing to a single subject (*damage*) and an adjective (*hurricane-caused*).

This might be what lead you to *is estimated* instead of the correct *estimated* answer.

Comment: Wov. That was definitely the case. I am impressed that you would be able to see it without my indication.